# ASP.NET Core - pass enum parameter from razor View to formaction

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Our team has inherited a system that we're trying to improve as we go along.

One thing we've noticed in our razor Views is many cases where different Controller Actions are written, that look like they could be parameterised.

for example, we have something a bit like this...

**ProcessSubmissionView.cshtml**

```
<button class="btn" type="submit" id="process-english-submission" formaction="ProcessWelshSubmission" formmethod="post">Process Welsh Submission</button>

<button class="btn" type="submit" id="process-welsh-submission" formaction="ProcessEnglishSubmission" formmethod="post">Process English Submission</button>
```

...that we'd prefer to write like this, i.e. call a single action (`ProcessSubmission`), but with a parameter - in this case, a 'Nationality' enum:

```
<button class="btn" type="submit" id="process-english-submission" formaction="ProcessSubmission" TODO PARAM= Nationality.English formmethod="post">Process English Submission</button>

<button class="btn" type="submit" id="process-welsh-submission" formaction="ProcessSubmission" TODO PARAM= Nationality.Welsh formmethod="post">Process Welsh Submission</button>
```

Given we have a `Nationality` enum, what should we put in the part above where it says *TODO PARAM= Nationality.English/Welsh*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `name` and `value` attrbutes on `<button type=“submit”>`.

```
<button type=“submit” name=“@Html.NameFor( m => m.Nationality )” value=“@( nameof(MyEnum.English) )”>english</button>
```

Comment: This looks like it's working in a quick test... In future, it would be great if we could pass in an instance of a class where the enum is passed above.  Can that be done easily?

Comment: @ArtieLeech Please elaborate on that question.

Comment: I've asked this follow-on question in a new SO question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61616599

Comment: Dai's approach suggested above worked perfectly for us, when passing an enum.  We just had to add the `Nationality` property to our ViewModel.